# Can you allow certain contacts to bypass the silent mode on Huawei P20 pro?

Tags: contacts, silent-mode, huawei-p20

I like my phone on silent through the night but need to have a certain contact to be able to ring (elderly relative). Not a problem when I had an iPhone, but can't find a way on Huawei P20 Pro.

Is there a way you can allow certain contacts to bypass the silent mode on a Huawei P20 Pro?

Answer (score 1):

You can find that in Settings → Sound → Do not disturb → Advanced parameters.

You will need to define a Priority Interrupt. Use 'Only contacts on whitelist', and add that contact to the whitelist.

My P20 pro is in French. I translated the menu words, though, not sure my wording is 100% identical to the original.

Comment: This answer is not really helping since "silent mode" is not the same as "do not disturb". In "do not disturb" all tones and vibrations are off. The original question was how we can make certain contacts trigger a ringtone even in silent mode.